# How to have alias name for controllers in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a  controller say, products and obviously access it like (www.xyz.com/index.php/products) but I want to access the same controller with (www.xyz.com/index.php/pro) by redirecting. I know that we can just make a controller pro and redirect it to products controller in index function. But I feel there are more simple ways without creating a second controller pro. Is it possible?

Comment: just add both aliases to the route, and have them both point at the same action. Google would've told you that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done, using Routing.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

```
$route['pro'] = 'products';
```

Comment: Hey there! Thank u.. It gives me the exact output I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Go to The **route.php** and the following lines

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Original controller name";
$route['pro'] = "Original controller name";
$route['(:any)'] = 'cart/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use concept of .htaccess .
This should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **application/config/routes.php** and add your alias to route

```
$route['alias'] = 'original_controller_name';
```

For more follow [official docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)